# Why is valet open *project name* giving me 502 error in my browser?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, nginx, laravel-valet

I'm running `valet open *project-name*` to display the project in my view but instead I get redirected to a page that's giving me a 502 error.

I've tried running `valet start` (all it did was restart `nginx`), ran `valet open *project-name*` again but I got the 502 error.

I also tried running `valet install` which installed `dnsmasq` via `brew`.  After this I ran `valet open *project-name*` again but I got the same 502 error.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you any error log to provide?

Comment: @MortezaPouretemadi hmm, it appears that if you create a Laravel project using `laravel new *project name*`, then inside the storage folder, there are no logs, only a `.gitignore` file.  However,  if you create a Laravel project using `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel *project name*`, then it does give logs.  Why's there a disparity of this nature?

Comment: There is no difference between them. In all cases your error logs are located in storage/logs